# How to implement cancel button in angular?

Tags: angular

Let's say if the man had some information in the input

```
<input type="text" name="text" [(ngModel)]='project.text'>
```

And if a person needs to erase or change data.

How can you implement a button that allows you to cancel all the changed operations on the field if the information was not saved.

Comment: whats your angular version btw ? is it js or 2.x or 6

Comment: Try `$setUntouched();`

Comment: @JitendraAhuja angular 5.2.0

Comment: Use $setPristine(); or $setUntouched();

Comment: @JitendraAhuja it's not going to work, I am n' using AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

If its angular js, you can use

```
$setPristine();
```

or

```
$setUntouched();
```

Other way is to reset the form which works perfectly fine:

```
this.form.reset();
```

where reset() is the inbuilt function which will clear the inputs for you when you want.

Note : ngModel is for two-way binding in angular, so you might be having "project" property in your component so if that value changes, your input will change accordingly.

Comment: I do not need cleaning,  I need to cancel the last operation. For Angular 2+ and not for AngularJS

Comment: In case the data is not saved and submitted yet, reset() is the cool option to go with. Else you need to have/implement deleteFunction() to delete the recently added input, where you'll need to go for delete query if the data is sent in Db somehow

Answer (score 0):

You (probably) cannot undo a save operation; the previous value has been overwritten and lost.

You can, however have a `copy` variable for the user to work with, until he/she hits save.

---

Template (use the copy):

```
<input type="text" name="text" [(ngModel)]='myModelCopy.name'>
```

Component:

```js
this.myModel = {
    name: 'John'
}
this.myModelCopy = {
    name: 'John'
}

// On save, replace value with copy (temporary) value.
// Use Object.assign() to make sure it's a COPY, not a reference
save(): void {
    this.myModel = Object.assign({}, this.myModelCopy);
}

// On cancel, revert to original
// Here too, use Object.assign()
cancel(): void {
    this.myModelCopy = Object.assign({}, this.myModel);
}

// On submit, update and send value
submit(): void {
    this.save();
    this.http.post(...)
}
```

Comment: I do not need cleaning,  I need to cancel the last operation